# solve $\sin x -2\cos (2x) = 1, 0 \le x \le 2\pi$

Tags: trigonometry

solve $\sin x -2\cos (2x) = 1, 0 \le x \le 2\pi$

Should I try and get the equation in the form $k\cos(x - \alpha)$ or replace $2\cos (2x)$ using the double angle formula?

If I use the double angle formula, I can expand to:

$\sin x - 2(1 - 2\sin^2 x) = 1$

$\sin x - 2 - 4\sin^2 x = 1$

$\sin x - 4\sin^2 x = 3$

$(\sin x)(1 - 4\sin x) = 3$

$\sin x= 3$ which is undefined

$4\sin x -1 = -3$

$\sin x =1 + \frac{-3}4$

$\sin x = \frac{1}4$

Sin is positive in 1st and second quadrants

$x = 14.4$ or $165.6$

Or in radians, $x = \frac{1}{4}$ or $x = 2.89$

Comment: Really love to know why this has been marked down.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You proceeded wrong after $\sin x(1 - 4\sin x) = 3$ (if we neglect that calculation mistake). You cannot assume that $\sin x = 3$. And it's because $3$ comes with the multiplication of both $\sin x$ and $1-4\sin x$, not alone of $\sin x$. It is only possible in the case of $something =0$.

You can proceed it by using the quadratic equation $$4 \sin^2 x + \sin x - 3 = 0$$

Comment: Check your calculations.  I obtain $4\sin^2x + \sin x - 3 = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

your assumption $\sin x=3$ is wrong.

take this case $x=6, y=\frac12$
$\implies xy=3$ , but you can see neither $x$ nor $y$ is equal to $3$.

Rather you can do one thing take take $3$ to other side then assign $\sin x=t$
then you have to solve quadratic equation and roots will be $$t=\frac34, -1$$$$\implies \sin x =-1\,\,\,\,\, or \,\,\,\,\,\frac34$$
$$\implies x=-\pi/2 \,\,\,\,\,or\,\,\,\,\, 0.848\mathrm{rad}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

You have rightly chosen Double angle formula.

But, $$0=4t^2+t-3=(4t-3)(t+1)$$